# Events, Delegates, Callback, INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, events, callback, delegates, inotifypropertychanged

Suppose I have the following:

```
class a 
{  
    List <SomeType> actions;

    ForEachMethod()
    {
        foreach (action in actions)
        {
            OtherFucntion(action);
        }
    }
}

class b 
{
    public Bool WasDoSomeThingSuccesful;

    OtherFunction (SomeType action)
    {
        WasDoSomeThingSuccesful = false;
        DoSomeThing();
    }
}
```

Now what I want to achieve: `DoSomeThing()` is some JS which will change the value of `WasDoSomethingSuccesfull` to true, but it is **async**, so I do not know when it will be.

So basically I want to watch if the property is set to true and when it is true I can continue with another action in actions in `ForEachMethod()`.

Even if I do understand the concept of delegates and events I do not know how to handle this when it is combined in this case..

Comment: Working in ASP .NET, winform, or WPF?

Comment: Do you want to notify class `a` when class `b` work completed?

Comment: exactly, but if there are other ways how to handle this I am literally open for everything, fe if this can be done by adding some new class or editing methods, I do not mind. My problem is that that JS changes the property async, so I can not do something like if (WasDoSomeThingSuccesful) {otherfunction ()}. Curently I am just using Thread.Sleep(value), but it is ineffective and if action is more complicated it can cause that sleep value is not sufficient.

Comment: But these both classes are not linked with each other. `a` not calling `b` and vice versa?

Comment: We can notify using event to that class which launch the class `b`

Comment: Can you show the code of that class which starts `b`

Comment: class A just have instance of class b which is passed by constructor of class A.

Comment: b = new B(browser, elementIdentificationJS);
a = new A(b)

Answer (score 0):

Use event just like in given below example for notification

```
public class A
{
    ...
    private void LaunchB()
    {
        var bObj = new B();
        bObj.OnTaskCompleted += TaskCompleted;
        bObj.StartWorking(); //some method call here
    }
    private void TaskCompleted(string status)
    {
        //notification from B comes
    }
    ...
}

public class B
{
    public delegate void TaskCompletedHandler(string status);
    public event TaskCompletedHandler OnTaskCompleted;
    private void DoWork()
    {
        if(completed)
        {
            ...
            if (OnTaskCompleted != null)
            {
               OnTaskCompleted("SUCCESS");
            }
        }
    }
}
```